# Using AWS from a Flask App running in ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

Currently, I have an application developed on Flask. This application uses AWS services using boto3 library which requires to set my AWS credentials in my personal computer (using AWS CLI), in order to run.

I want to run my Flask app in ElasticBeanstalk, however. How can I set my AWS credentials in my ElasticBeanstalk server, in order to boto3 to run properly?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your credentials into `Environment properties`, following the AWS doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html

1. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console, and in the Regions list, select your AWS Region.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Environments, and then choose the name of your environment from the list.
3. In the navigation pane, choose Configuration.
4. In the Software configuration category, choose Edit.
5. Under Environment properties, enter key-value pairs.

And then you can access them from your Flask application

```
    import os

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', 
                  aws_access_key_id=os.environ['your_key'], 
                  aws_secret_access_key=settings.os.environ['your_secret_key'], 
                  region_name=os.environ['your_region_key']
    )
```